# pass variable but not show in the url?

Tags: url, seo

I want to pass a variable in my URL but not show it in the URL for SEO purposes

e.g www.mywebsite.com/Search?city=NYC should looks like www.mywebsite.com/Search and still be able to retrieve the value of "city" on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used Rewrite rules to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a POST request and you're done. However, is a common pratice to use GET request for search forms because the user can bookmark the url. Using POST, this isn't possible.

Comment: Every link is an <a> tag. If you meant that you use a simple link, you have to use JavaScript to send a post request.

Comment: Thanks Aurelio, let me ask my question in a different way. Can I use a rewrite rule to not show the variable in the URL but still pass the variable?

Comment: In the way you want, it isn't possible.